How to use ReCaptcha with Angular 17 with Standalone Components
I need to implement captcha to prevent spam atacks etc. But the more I search and trying to find something about how to do it in angular 17 (with standalone components) the more I feel like there's no way to do it.
I almost finished project, so I dont want to make it non standalone. I see that there are ng-recaptcha documentation and a lot of tutorials where recaptcha module placed in providers in the @NgModule, but I can't find how to provide recaptcha in app.config.ts.

"ng-recaptcha": "^13.2.1",

I tried to do it without providing in app config and I've got error that there is no provider for recaptchV3. Also providing it nowhere, I can't to specify my site key.
Example of code where I tried something:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from '../../shared/modal/modal.component';
import { UserService } from '../../shared/user.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ReCaptchaV3Service } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment.development';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-username-change-modal',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './username-change-modal.component.html',
  styleUrl: './username-change-modal.component.css',
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ModalComponent],
})
export class UsernameChangeModalComponent implements OnInit {
  usernameForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private recaptchaV3Service: ReCaptchaV3Service
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usernameForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
      ]),
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.recaptchaV3Service.execute('changeUsername').subscribe((token) => {
      token
        ? this.userService
            .changeUsername(this.usernameForm.value.username)
            .subscribe(() => {
              this.toastr.success('Username changed successfully');
            })
        : this.toastr.error('Recaptcha failed');
    });
  }
}



this might help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-recaptcha-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

@browsermator, there are providers in @NgModule, but my providers are in app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {   providers: [     provideRouter(routes),     provideClientHydration(),     provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([authInterceptor])),     provideAnimations(),     provideToastr(),   ], };
I need to know how to provide it there, because I use angular without '--no-standalone' flag (it means I don't have @NgModule like I said in question above).

this one looks like a standalone version but it's labeled as v16 angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-recaptcha-example-whpssk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In order to use ReCaptcha with Angular 17 Standalone Components do this:
On your app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      routes,
    ),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimations(),
    { provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, useValue: environment.siteKeyV3 },
    {
      provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
      useValue: {
        siteKey: environment.siteKeyV2,
      } as RecaptchaSettings,
    },
  ],

Then in your component you need to import Recaptcha Modules from ng-recaptcha
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, RecaptchaModule,
    RecaptchaFormsModule,
    RecaptchaV3Module,],
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrl: './your-component.component.scss'
})

Hope it helps !!

Thanks, made it earlier and I actually realized recently that when I'm installing packages via 'ng add' command (not 'npm' one) providers would be added automatically
